# Issue in storing values in grid view without database

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I am following this tutorial http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Blogs/8274/insert-data-in-grid-view-without-using-database.aspx.
I am doing extactly the same as done in it. Bascially I have to store values in grid view without database. Now the issue is that when user will click second  time Button1_Click() (as mentioned in this tutorial) button, the previous row is discarded. I want that whenever user will click on button that value should be saved in grid. Please help me !!!

```
    DataTable dt;
    protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr[0] = txtUrl.Text;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        grdDummy.DataSource = dt;
        grdDummy.DataBind();

    }
    private void BindGrid()
    {
        dt = new DataTable();
        DataColumn dc1 = new DataColumn("Name");
        dt.Columns.Add(dc1);
        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
        grdDummy.DataSource = dt;
        grdDummy.DataBind();
    }
```

Note that BindGrid() is called on page_load event..

Comment: show your code what you have done.

Comment: Without a database, how do you intend to store state between requests? You *could* store it at the client, but I'd advise against it. You could use a session, you could persist it to a file... but we can't really make that decision for you.

Comment: I have to use this way. it is compulsary for me!!!! PLEASE HELP MEE!

Comment: I  think this is mvc code @NadeemKhan

Comment: @user2179026: what error are you getting, try debugging the code

Comment: No error message, but the issue is when user click on the button second time with new values in textbox. The older value is discarded from grid.

Comment: Show me your gridview aspx code

Comment: When are you calling the BindGrid() method? Each time this method is called it will clear out the data table as it's being initialized there. You can try initialize it up the top instead. Additionally I've never had to use DataBind() on my dgv in WinForms, not sure if asp.net handles them different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code:
First make Serializable Class which contents your Fields e.g.

```
`[Serializable]
public class Class1
{
    public Class1()
    {
        //
        // TODO: Add constructor logic here
        //
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

Then on your page, use below code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

Class1 obj = new Class1();
static List<Class1> lst = new List<Class1>();

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   obj.Name = TextBox1.Text;
   obj.Address = TextBox2.Text;

   lst.Add(obj);

   GridView1.DataSource = lst; 
   GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

And on designing page

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="GridView1" AutoGenerateColumns="true">
    </asp:GridView>
```

Hope it helps. :)